# Problem with Arduino Uno and SIM900 shield logical communication (rx & tx)

Tags: shields, gsm

[image: these is my shield]

The logical communication(rx & tx) between the shield and Arduino Uno doesn't  work. Arduino (rx & tx) supply  is 0 & 5 V but this is 0 & 2.8 V. What am I to do?

Comment: Post a link to where you bought the shield. It's extremely unlikely that a shield designed to plug right into a 5 V board would not also include any necessary level shifting circuitry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [logic level converter](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/using-the-logic-level-converter).

A logic level converter is a small device that converts between different logic levels, for example between 5V and 3.3V.

I am not affiliated with Sparkfun, I just think they are the most informative source.

Comment: I think ur right